# Trouble binding to TCP Service

Tags: android

SocketService.java:

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    int mStartMode;
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    boolean mAllowRebind;
    String IPValue;
    String PortValue;
    Socket socket;
    byte data[];


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SocketService getServerInstance() {
            return SocketService.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("SERVICE CREATED");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        IPValue = sharedPreferences.getString("IPValue", "NA");
        PortValue = sharedPreferences.getString("PortValue", "NA");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println("SERVICE ONSTARTCOMMAND");
        return mStartMode;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("SERVICE BOUND");

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IPValue);
            int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(PortValue);
            System.out.println(serverAddr.getHostAddress() + serverPort);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mBinder;
    }

    public void send_mesage(String msg) {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(msg);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I've fetched the IP and Port in `onCreate`, and made the socket connection in `onBind`.

Now in my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public String IPValue;
    public String PortValue;
    public Socket socket;
    boolean mBounded;
    SocketService mServer;

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service is disconnected", 1000).show();
            mBounded = false;
            mServer = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
            mBounded = true;
            SocketService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (SocketService.LocalBinder)service;
            mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
        bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
```

**This works perfectly, my TCP server shows the connection as created**.

Now I wanted to access the `send_message()` method inside `SocketService`. 
So I simply added `mServer.send_mesage("HELLO WORLD!");` after `bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` in the `onCreate()` of my Activity.

BUT this causes everything to break down. My connection is NOT established on my server, and the app FCs. Here are the logs:

```
10-21 15:37:33.945    9125-9125/com.example.myfirstapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 313ms
10-21 15:37:48.985    9125-9125/com.example.myfirstapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-21 15:37:48.985    9125-9125/com.example.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
10-21 15:37:49.015    9125-9125/com.example.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NullPointerException right on that new line I just added!

I don't understand what could be causing this problem! Even strangely, apparently the `onCreate` and `onBind` methods of the service aren't even called this time, because I don't see the output of the print statements I've put in each of them.

Any help?

Comment: What line is line 57 of MainActivity?

Comment: It's the new line I just added which calls `send_message`.

Answer (score 0):

mServer is null until such time as the callback onServiceConnected() fires. Although you've told it to bind on the previous line, it takes time to bind. You have to wait till after the call back before you can refer to mServer

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Although I can't figure out how to fix this. Can you point out a few examples?

Comment: Presumably you want to send the message in response to a button press or some event, after you've edited the message, so in the buttons onClick just check the mServer for not null, then send the message. (And don't do it on the main thread either! else you'll get a NetworkOnMainThreadException)